# Xamarin iOS 10 WebView freeze

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ios10

I have noticed some Xamarin iOS WebView rendering problems after upgrading to iOS 10.

Basically after returning back to the app after screen has been locked and then unlocked causes web view content to freeze. After returning to the app, the user cannot scroll or tap the items on the web view for the most items. The sample attached app uses BBC web site, for this web site, the upper part works more or less fine, the bottom doesn't. But for our internal web site, everything is frozen on iOS 10.

I have reproduced the behaviour only on iOS 10 and cannot reproduce it on the previous iOS version (tested on 9.3.5) or any version on the simulator.

I have attached the sample app that demonstrates the problem: [Xamarin Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zqp5xn6fc2ao2sy/WebViewLockTest.zip?dl=0):

- compile the app
- run the app
- press **Load page** and wait till the web site loads
- lock the device
- unlock the device
- on iOS **10** you should observe unresponsive layout
- on iOS **9.3.5** the web site should work fine

I'm not sure if it is Xamarin or iOS issue.

Environment:

- OS: macOS 10.12.1
- Xamarin Studio: 6.1.1 (build 17)
- Xamarin Forms: 2.3.1.114
- Device: iOS 10.1.1

**Update 1**

I have created a very similar native iOS app and cannot reproduce the problem: [XCode Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hi3tmn3au9p51yj/WebViewLockTest_IOS.zip?dl=0).

Seems to be Xamarin (Forms) bug.

**Update 2**

Retested on Xamarin Forms 2.3.3.163-pre3, still the same :(